# pass a directory name from one coordinator to another in oozie

Tags: oozie, hadoop2, oozie-coordinator

I have a coordinator-A running which has workflow that generates output to a directory

```
 /var/test/output/20161213-randomnumber/
```

now i need to pass the dir name "20161213-randomnumber" to another coordinator-B which needs to start as soon as the workflow of the coordinator-A is completed.

I am not able to find any pointers on how to pass the file name or how can the coordinator-B be triggered with the directory generated by co-ordinator A.

How ever i have seen numerous examples on triggering the coordinators for a specific date, daily, monthly, weekly dataset. In my case the dataset is not time dependent. It can arrive arbitrarily .

Comment: Why not add a sub-workflow action in the first workflow itself, which calls the second workflow?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can add one more action to put one empty trigger file (trig.txt) after your data generation script(/var/test/output/20161213-randomnumber/) action in your coordinator A. Then in your coordinator B add the data dependency to point to the trigger file, if it is there corrdinator B will start. Once B is getting started you can clear the trigger file for the next run.

You can use this data dependency to solve the problem. you can not pass parameter from one coordinator to another coordinator.